# Symfony Sonata MediaBundle, i cannot upload a big size PDF

Tags: file, symfony, upload, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

I cannot upload a big size PDF File via `Sonata MediaBundle`, this is the error i got :

Uncaught PHP Exception `Twig_Error_Runtime`: "Impossible to access a key ("default") on a boolean variable ("") in `SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_edit_form.html.twig` at line 59" at `Work\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 4990
Context: { "exception": "Object(Twig_Error_Runtime)" }`

it goes normal with small size files,

if anyone can help would be so great, thank you :)

Comment: What PDF size are you unable to upload ?

Comment: the file size is 9 Mo

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, i had to change this in the php.ini :

post_max_size = 50M

upload_max_filesize = 50M

Comment: Please make sure to mark your question as "Resolved" if it does. Thank you.